# Resume downloading consequent videos when youtubeDL fails to download a video

Tags: python-2.7, exception, youtube-dl

I'm trying to develop a python script to download a bunch of youtube videos which are inputted from a csv file using the youtube-dl module. The script stops as the download fails for a single video. I need the script to continue downloading the next videos ignoring the videos that cannot be downloaded. Can some one please help me on how to handle this in python?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the `youtube-dl` command you can use the [`--ignore-errors` flag](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/c84d3a557de8eddc8e63adbd11ab40877f52c502/README.md#options).

If you are using the `youtube_dl` module from python you have to use the [`ignoreerrors` parameter](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/b286f201a8424e00cc91d27adcf53a5249b8a3b9/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L147):

```python
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors': True}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['<URL>'])
```

Comment: Hi  

My python code has that option enabled:

ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors':True,'progress_hooks': [my_hook],'format': fmt,'writeinfojson':True,'logger': MyLogger()}
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([URL])

But it is not able to bypass and program exits with below error message
ERROR: VqzpEw69Tze: YouTube said: This video does not exist.

Comment: For me it shows the error message but it doesn't raise any exception (which seems to be what you ask for).

Comment: You'll get a better help if you open a new issue in the youtube-dl tracker (https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/new) posting the code you are running.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question but the problem cropped up for me and I found a simple solution.

I think the problem here is that youtube_dl is catching any errors that come up and then reporting them by way of it's own internal message output routines, so the exception is 'consumed' before it gets to the calling code. This is probably appropriate for the command line utility but creates a hurdle when using it in native python code. Fortunately the developers of youtube_dl provide us a way to intercept error messages and handle them without the need to jack around with the youtube_dl internals. Unfortunately they're pretty light on both explanations and examples, but if you check the 'developer instructions' of the readme there's an example of a custom logger class.

With a little modification, we can use this class to store error messages (or warnings, or whatever) and then check for them in lieu of using a try/except block:

```
class MyLogger(object):

def __init__(self):
    self._message_queue = []

def debug(self, msg):
    print('[DEBUG]' + msg)

def warning(self, msg):
    pass

def error(self, msg):
    self._message_queue.append(msg)
    print(msg)

def get_message(self):
    return None if not len(self._message_queue) else \
           self._message_queue.pop()
```

Import the logger class, instantiate it, and pass it as an argument in your options string for youtube_dl.

```
import mylogger
...
loggr = mylogger.MyLogger()
...
ydl_opts = { 'logger': loggr }
```

Now, when it's time to take an action based on the presence of an error, you can check the message queue in your logger object to see if there's something to do:

```
possible_error = loggr.get_message()
if possible_error is None:
    #do normal code
else:
    #check the content of the error string and do something with it.
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as you, this is caused by the unavailableness if some videos in you list due to some issues.

And I solved the problem by this:

```py
video_list = ['aaa','bbb',...,'ccc']

for each in video_list:
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        try:
            ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + each])
        except yt_dlp.utils.DownloadError:
            print('Video {0} is not available!'.format(each))
```

This solution works but it might not be elegant  as the package itself has implemented its way to ignore the download error, thus the more appropriate way is as Top answer suggested

```py
ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors': True}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['<URL>'])
```